# Best practice to delete big portion of big mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a log table in mysql that inserts 1 000 000 rows per day for the past 6 months. (Approximately 180 000 000 rows)

This table requires 54GB of space whereas rest of tables within the same database only require 2GB.

I plan to delete this log table manually using:

```
DELETE FROM log_table ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 1000000
```

It is intended to keep approximately 10 000 000 most recent rows.

Should I use some specific procedure such as table optimization, stopping temporarily traffic to the database, use higher / lower limit, make a copy of database to make sure data is not fragmented on the HDD and so on?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with the procedure that you have mentioned above. However, generally speaking, it is a best practice to keep a backup of the database.

Comment: @AbhrapratimNag - cool so its not going to be a problem, that 54GB of fragmented data is going to disappear, it wont affect future performance of the rest of the tables in the database? Sure backup is being kept.

Comment: i dont see any problem with that, however, it is better to ask / consult this situation in dba.stackexchange.com The database administrators can give a more accurate or detailed perspective or solution(s)